# MYSQL, When defining a table does the UNIQUE constraint have to be used in conjunction with an INTEGER or can it be any datatype?

Tags: mysql, sql, unique-constraint, mysql-error-1005

I am wanting to have a label column (`VARCHAR`) and I want it to be unique, but when I try to create the table it seems to be throwing an error. Can a unique constraint only be used in conjunction with an INTEGER or will it work with other datatypes as well. The error I am getting is (`ERRNO 150`)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user`(
user_id INT  NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
username    VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`password`  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `element`(
element_id  INT NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
label   VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
parent_id   INT NULL,
user_id INT NOT NULL,
created_on  TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
edited_on   TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
UNIQUE(label),
KEY element_1 (label),
CONSTRAINT FK_element_1 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES `user` (user_id),
CONSTRAINT FK_element_2 FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES `element` (element_id)
);
```

Comment: @OMG: Except `TEXT` and `BLOB`, right?

Comment: I have posted the SQL querey. This is only the second table to be created if needed I could give you the SQL for the one prior.

Comment: @ypercube: Dunno why `TEXT` wouldn't be supported - there's no mention of any data type requirements for unique constraints in MySQL [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html) or [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/constraint-primary-key.html)

Comment: +1: For updating to add the CREATE TABLE statement.  Checking the info in the tag for MySQL Error 1005 points to the foreign keys - post the other CREATE TABLE statements.  Very likely the issue is order -- the tables `element` is referencing likely haven't been created when the statement is being run.

Comment: Have you already created table `user` ?

Comment: @OMG: Oh, yes, I meant that they can be only prefix-indexed: *"BLOB and TEXT columns also can be indexed, but a prefix length must be given."* Anyway, this is irrelevant to the problem, it seems.

Comment: @ypercube - the user table get's created first, and then this table after.

Comment: ANd tabel `user` has a field `user_id` ? If no, that's the reason for the error.

Comment: Also check: Has the table `user` actually been created?

Comment: I think your default engine is `MyISAM`.

Comment: ran these queries on my local installation and they ran without problems.  Running Percona but it should still work in MySQL.

Comment: No, i was wrong. MyISAM ignores FOREIGN KEYS.

Comment: The only way I can have this error, if the first table is created with MyISAM engine and the second (tried to be created) with InnoDB.

Comment: @ypercude - So I should be sure to specify the engine after each?

Comment: @Brook: Yes. Or better, change you default engine into InnoDB, since you want to have Foreign Key constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can have this error, if the first table is created with `MyISAM` engine and the second (tried to be created) with `InnoDB`.

Check the definition of the created table `user`, using:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE user ;
```

If that's the case, drop it and recreate it with:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user`(
user_id INT  NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
username    VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`password`  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)
 ENGINE = InnoDB ;
```